# Best common type with as const in nested array

Tags: typescript

Consider following snippet

```
const test = [
  {
    a: [
      {
        b: 3 as const
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    a: [
      {
        b: 4 as const
      }
    ]
  }
];

test.map(({ a }) => a.map(({ b }) => b));
// Expected inferred type
// a: { b: 3 | 4 }[]
// Actual inferred type
// a: { b: 3 }[] | { b: 4 }[]
```

Typescript throws error on `a.map` part of the code, where it cannot apply `.map` on two different types (2nd comment in the code)

With the use of `as const` is it generalizing properly?